# Page View controller in container view with data from model

Tags: swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have a container view that shows a page view controller. This view controller then shows 2 of the same view controllers and I can page back and forth.

```
        import UIKit

class ViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.delegate = self
self.dataSource = self

let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page1")
let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page2")

pages.append(page1)
pages.append(page2)

setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
print("previous Index", pages[previousIndex])
return pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
print("next Index", pages[nextIndex])
return pages[nextIndex]
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
return pages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
return 0
}
}
```

What I would like to do is create only one view controller, and then populate that view controller with data from an array

Array:

```
var pageTitles : Array<String> = ["God vs Man", "Cool Breeze", "Fire Sky"]
var pageImages : Array<String> = ["page1.png", "page2.png", "page3.png"]
```

Is this possible with a container view controller presenting a page view controller?

Any help would be appreciated...

Denis Angell

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage only one controller with multi data and `UIPageController`, you should create a view controller and to do something like that:

```
class PageViewController: UIViewController { // Id: 'PageViewController'
    // MARK: @IBOutlet

    /// Menu button item.
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    /// Pagination controller.
    @IBOutlet weak var pagination: UIPageControl!

    // MARK: Variable
    struct Page {
        var title: String
        var image: String
        init(title: String, image: String) {
            self.title = title
            self.image = image
        }
    }
    let data: [Page] = []
    var currentIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Init data
        data.append(Page(title: "title1" , image: "page1.png"))
        data.append(Page(title: "title2" , image: "page2.png"))

        setValues(currentIndex)

        // Setup slide handler
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                 action: #selector(PageViewController(_:)))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                  action: #selector(PageViewController(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    /**
     Handle swipes allows to switch page.
     */
    func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        let size = self.data.count
        let currentPosition = self.pagination.currentPage

        if sender.direction == .left && currentPosition < size-1 {
            nextPage()
        } else if sender.direction == .right && currentPosition > 0 {
            previousPage()
        }
    }

    private func setValues(index: Int) {
        self.pagination.currentPage = currentIndex
        self.title = pageTitles[index]
        self.image = pageImages[index]
    }

    // Button or see UIPageControl @IBOutlet
    private func nextPage() {
        currentIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        print("next Index", pages[currentIndex])
        setValues(currentIndex)
    }

    // Button or see UIPageControl @IBOutlet
    private func previousPage() {
        currentIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        print("next Index", pages[currentIndex])
        setValues(currentIndex)
    }

    // Other functions...
    // ...

}
```